# Homemade Fabreze mystery substance

Tags: cleaning

My wife made a cleaning solution of isopropyl alchohol (1200mL), baking soda (100 mL) and distilled water(2400 mL). She first mixes baking soda with warm water till it dissolves.  Then adds the isopropyl.  Sometimes, a solid material will form at the bottom of the solution. What is it? It has us confused...

Comment: Is the IPA warm? First guess is a precipitate of baking soda due to cooling of the solution.

Comment: No, it is not warm. It does look crystalline though.  Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it.